# VMware Horizon View and android WebCam

Tags: android, vmware

I test "VMware Horizon View" for modernize the job process and I want to know if is possible to use Camera of Android device with Horizon View Agent.

Because for me it's don't work.

Thank

Matth.

Answer (score 0):

It does not supported. The feature Realtime Audio Video support on vmware view windows/mac/linux client. But it does not supported on andriod client.
Please refer to :
[VMware-view-andriod-client-Guide](https://www.vmware.com/pdf/horizon-view/horizon-view-client-android-document.pdf%20%20%20vmware-view-andriod-client-guide)